# ¿Enlaces internos con name o id?

Tags: html, html5

Si quiero hacer referencia a una parte dentro de alguna página uso enlaces con una almohadilla (`#`); como por ejemplo: `http://mi.pagina.com/#ancla`, saltará dentro de la página a la parte identificada con el anclaje `#ancla`.

Hay dos métodos que funcionan para crear ese anclaje/enlace interno:

1. Usando un `a` con el atributo `name`:

   ```
   <h2><a name="ancla"></a>Título de Sección</h2>
   ```
2. o usando cualquier elemento con un `id`:

   ```
   <h2 id="ancla">Título de Sección</h2>
   ```

Excepto en casos excepcionales (comprobé que los navegadores reaccionan de manera diferente en caso de conflicto), parece que los dos funcionan igual. **¿Existe alguna diferencia entre ambos métodos? ¿Alguna de las dos formas es mejor que la otra?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**¿Existe alguna diferencia entre ambos métodos?**

La diferencia principal en la teoría es que el primer método es "obsoleto pero conforme" en HTML5, en otras palabras se puede seguir usando aunque no se debe, según [W3: Obsolete but conforming features](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features) se debería utilizar el atributo `id`:

> **Authors should not specify the name attribute on a elements.** If the attribute is present, its value must not be the empty string and must neither be equal to the value of any of the IDs in the element's home subtree other than the element's own ID, if any, nor be equal to the value of any of the other name attributes on a elements in the element's home subtree. If this attribute is present and the element has an ID, then the attribute's value must be equal to the element's ID. In earlier versions of the language, this attribute was intended as a way to specify possible targets for fragment identifiers in URLs. **The id attribute should be used instead.**

La diferencia en la práctica **debería ser**, según la especificación, que el navegador buscara primero un elemento con un `id` igual al especificado en el anclaje (`#ancla`), el cual es 'sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas', si no lo encuentra entonces buscará un elemento con el atributo `name`.

La explicación de este segundo punto se encuentra aquí: [Navigating to a fragment: The indicated part of the document](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#an-indicated-part-of-the-document)

> 1 Apply the URL parser algorithm to the URL, and let fragid be the fragment component of the resulting URL record.
>
> ...
>
> 7 No decoded fragid: If there is an a element in the DOM that has a name attribute whose value is exactly equal to fragid (not decoded fragid), then the first such element in tree order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.

---

**¿Alguna de las dos formas es mejor que la otra?**

Basándonos en la teoría, o sea la documentación de HTML5 que vimos en el punto anterior, el mejor sería el segundo método, pues el primero no es válido y puede que algún día no lo soporten los navegadores que sigan la especificación de forma estricta.

Comment: Buena respuesta y muy completa.